# EXCEPTION: No provider for t! (t -> t)

Tags: angular

Since i went from angular   "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0" to   "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.8"

I have this error when creating a form ... The issue seems to come from the input ngControl :

```
    <div id="global">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Créer un compte</h2> </div>
  <form (ngSubmit)="register()" [ngFormModel]="userForm">
         <input ngControl="email" type="text" id="right-label">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="small-3 columns">
                 <md-progress-linear class="md-accent" mode="determinate" [value]="strengthValue"></md-progress-linear>
              </div>
            </div>
        <div class="row">
          <button md-raised-button class="md-raised md-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!userForm.valid">S'incrire</button>
        </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

If I remove this line

```
<input ngControl="email" type="text" id="right-label">
```

The error disappear (but i need it for my form obviously )

Here is the begining of my .ts

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {FORM_PROVIDERS,FormBuilder, ControlGroup, Control, Validators} from 'angular2/common';
import {MATERIAL_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-material/all';
import {Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';
import {ValidationService} from '../../services/validation.services';
import {ControlMessages} from './control-messages.component';
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES,NgControl} from 'angular2/common';
@Component({
  selector: 'inscription-modal-cmp',
  providers: [FORM_PROVIDERS]
})
@View({
  templateUrl: './components/inscription-modal/inscription-modal.html',
  styleUrls: ['./components/inscription-modal/inscription-modal.css'],
  directives: [MATERIAL_DIRECTIVES,ControlMessages,FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
```

Do you have an idea ? 
Also the issue is fixed if i use the .dev bundle....

Thanks

Comment: would you have a jsfiddle or a plnkr ?

Comment: See this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6374) (all in to that is related to that one). To see the full error message use the `dev` bundles (`angular2.dev.js`)

Comment: Will do a plnkr when I have time.  When I use the dev bundle angular2.dev.js the problem disappear...